# Approach for a Cheese material with SSS in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, subsurface-scattering

I want to make realistic looking cheese, I think the best way to do it is by using Subsurface Scattering in some way.

Here is a reference image.

[image]

Comment: Here is a start https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/blender-cycles-lighting/9781782164609/ch10s03.html, you will probably have to play around with them and a really good lighting setup is going to be needed.

Comment: Hmmm nice and appetizing piece of cheese :)

Comment: I don't have a complete answer so I won't bother but I think for the dark area around the crust, I would try and use Vertex Colors to help with that part.  You can access them using the 'Attribute' node by entering 'Col' if you are using the default name.

Comment: [Cantal](https://www.shutterstock.com/en/search/cantal+fromage) + [Pauillac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%A2teau_Grand-Puy-Lacoste) simple pleasure of the life.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're right, SSS is what you want.

An SSS shader is pretty much it as far as the base shader goes, but a few textures and some diffuse shading for the scratches won't go amiss:

[image]

Also make sure the rind is a separate manifold mesh (i.e has a surface on the side against the cheese). Otherwise, light which should be blocked by the rind will enter the cheese material and get scattered out, giving a rather unconvincing transition without any darkening:

[image]

Cheese material:

[image]

Note the scattering radius values. These were just guessed at with some eyeballing, so you may want to play with them a bit to get the effect you want.

The control how far red, green, and blue light can be scattered, with the top value being red and the bottom being blue.

The sharpness and texture blur on the SSS node are both `0`.

Comment: Very nice answer