# Realistic vegetable shading

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shaders

How can I have the pepper look more realistic? I have been trying a few different nodes options as shown below in Cycles, but something still looks like a plastic

**Node with Subsurface scattering:**

[image]

[image]

If I replace the subsurface scattering with **Diffuse shader**, then I get the result below

[image]

It looks better with SSS but requires longer rendering time and more noise.
I was wondering if there's easier way to make things work better here.

**Overall scene** looks like:

[image]

Ps. I'd be happy to get any recommendations about how to improve rest of the scene, I know stem is way behind being realisting, its just a plastic looking now :(

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure you don't want to mix SSS by a layer weight. I've never seen that done. One thing that might help, is to not have the fresnel so glossy. It really just looks too glossy. I would instead of using a frensl node, take a layer weight node, and use a color ramp or RGB curves to modify it until it looks about right. I would just make sure to keep it less glossy.

Comment: thanks for reply, ok I removed the layered weight and reduced the glossiness and add Layer weight with RBG curve instead of fresnel, i will share a photo once i finish render

Answer (score 7):

Try looking at some reference images (google images is often the easiest method) to see what peppers look like.

My observations:

- Very irregular shapes, usually with subtle bumps and nicks.
- Most peppers seem to have rather rough reflections.
- Extremely subtle color variations in the skin.
- Little bits of "imperfection", such as tiny specs of dirt in crevices/around the stem

With some hastily slapped together procedural textures, I attempted to simulate these things:

[image]

For the irregular shape, I used two displace modifiers. One doing macro displacement in all directions, the other doing subtle displacement along the normals.

[image]

To get the subtle variations in color I used a noise texture. For the small nicks I used a bump map. For the rough reflections I used a much rougher glossy shader.

[image]

You'd probably be able to get more realistic results with image textures, but perhaps this will give you some ideas.

---

In my scene I didn't end up using SSS for the pepper, as with my lighting setup the results were indistinguishable from a diffuse shader (and SSS was much noisier). However this might not be the case in your scene, so keep in mind that [thickness and inner geometry matter](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18607/3710). Peppers are usually hollow with a core running through the middle, so a solidify modifier and a displaced cylinder in the middle should approximate that pretty well.

Comment: wow, thanks that's a great answer , i will study and apply it asap. and yes you're right I need to use more irregular shapes to make it look more realistic. I will upload the result once i finish, thanks

Comment: thanks again @gandalf3 , i have made some changes according to things you showed with displacement and surely it is much better here [link](http://i.imgur.com/pt5m1QP.png) and when rendered [here](http://i.imgur.com/qQyRJgR.jpg) on the right old version, on the left new version with all those irregular touches,  there's one more thing I want to have a small area of bright yellow colour under the stem and then fading into the rest of red-orange colour,  like [here](http://i.imgur.com/M5pMLfX.png) , i cant figure it out yet, any suggestions on it? thanks

Comment: @ideorium I'd find/make an image texture with any such color variations and use that to replace the *main color variations* section in my setup.

Comment: thanks @gandalf3 i will try to do so, however i wish there was a way around to do in blender though.

Comment: Well you *could* do it procedurally, but it will likely be much easier to get a realistic result using an image texture (either made externally or [painted in blender](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/painting.html))