# Glossy Shader not working to create realistic texture as I wanted it too

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I'm trying to use the glossy shader to create that realistic effect on real world objects, but it seems as though if the glossy shader is not working as I please.

This is what it looks like:[image]

I'm trying to give it a white reflection over the orange, but I'm not sure if i have to put something into the glossy shader, but I don't know.
Thanks if you know what i should do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a nice reflection you'll want to add

- **More light**
  Materials, especially glossy or refractive materials, are hugely dependent on the surrounding light sources. Try adding a nice big mesh light (or area lamp) for the material to reflect
- **Fresnel**
  Light tends to reflect off of materials more at glancing angles, and reflect less when hitting a surface straight on. If you look at your top-down reference picture/texture, there is hardly any visible specular reflection ("specular" refers to perfect or mirror-like reflections, such as the sharp white highlights)

  To simulate this, add a *Fresnel* node, plug your bump/normal map into it, and connect it to the *Mix factor* of the mix node which is mixing in your glossy shader.

  This will make a big difference, especially on surfaces with lots of small variations in angle.

[image]

[image]

In this example I slightly complicated things by giving the rind a lower [IOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index) than the rest. A more simple setup could just connect one of the fresnel nodes straight to the mix shader (both selected). However given that the rind and fruity parts of the orange have quite different optical properties, you probably do want to simulate that in some way.

[image]

---

Note that an actual orange is quite complex, with the fruity parts being translucent with a visible internal structure. To properly simulate one, you might want to model the slices and rind separately and use a translucency, SSS or volume shader (somewhat similarly to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18591/599)).

Comment: When dealing with concepts of "whiteness" in @gandalf3's reply, it is worth realizing that they are display referred concepts. This means dynamic range also plays a role in your rolloff to white in the display referred domain. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im/46940#46940 if this is alien to you.